# Wordpress theme and PHPMailer class

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer

Can I use a theme specific(a separate copy in my theme's folder) `PHPMailer` Class for sending emails?

I am asking this because I have some issue on using `wp_mail()`, It's not taking header, I have searched and got many infos related to use Filters for header name and mail, but its not working, might be because of some plugin activated.

So is it possible to add PHPMailer class, and use it in ajax callback functions?

I tried but site goes blank.

Answer (score -1):

[WP already uses PHPMailer](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L193) in its implementation of `wp_mail`... You may have to do a little digging to get at it, but you should be able to either make use of `wp_mail`'s PHPMailer instance, or at least load it from WP's default libraries without having to bundle another copy.

That you can even contemplate adding a functional library like PHPMailer to a wordpress *theme* shows what a disaster the design of WP's themes is! Repeat after me: "separation of concerns!"

Comment: I totally understand what you are getting at, but there really isn't that much difference between adding a functional library as a plugin or including it as a theme. There are totally legitimate reasons for wanting to keep everything bundled together in a theme rather than building theme functionality around conditional checks for plugins/libraries being available or not.Heck, you could even have the theme just store the dependancies and have them download and install updates on deployment like any other standard application.

Comment: That would be a huge improvement, but as it stands you can break a site merely by changing the theme; in other words, themes are not themes, but arbitrary, non-interchangeable bundles of appearance and functionality. Anyway, my comment ws directed at WP, not you, and my suggestion still stands - PHPMailer is already there, so why bundle another copy?